# invalid operands when multiplying NSInteger by any number

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i am trying to print an integer property multiplied by another number as follows:

```
NSLog(@"ReceivedData: %i", (self.receivedData*10));
```

but Xcode highlights that line in red and says:invalid operands

I tried the following

```
NSInteger *newVal = @([self receivedData] * 10);
NSLog(@"ReceivedData: %i", (int) self.receivedData);
```

but I receive `invalid operands error`

```
receivedData is NSInteger*
```

how to solve it

Comment: What is `receivedData`? `NSNumber`?

Comment: assuming that your receivedData is an NSNumber, ([self.receivedData intValue]*10)

Comment: @va it is NSInteger *

Comment: @ReinierMelian it is Nsinteger*

Comment: `NSInteger` is **not** an object. Remove the asterisk. And rather than casting to `int` and lose precision use the `%li` specifier.

Comment: @vadian ok..now after removing the * it is working..but if there was an asterisk??

Comment: It depends on the class. `NSNumber` objects cannot be multiplied directly (see Reinier's comment) `NSDecimalNumber` has math operation methods.

Answer (score 1):

You are not multiplying an NSInteger with a number, you are multiplying a pointer to an NSInteger with a number, which is not allowed, because multiplying a pointer by a number is nonsense.

99.99% chance that receivedData shouldn't be an NSInteger* but an NSInteger. NSInteger is not an object.

The line

```
NSInteger *newVal = @([self receivedData] * 10);
```

shows that you should go back to basics and actually learn the programming language that you are using.